# How to get sub property from json result?

Tags: import, json-format

I'm brand new to *Mathematica* and I imported a json:

```
data = ImportString["{\"x\":1,\"y\":1}", "json"]
```

and result:

```
{"x" -> 1, "y" -> 1}
```

Now `data` denotes `{"x" -> 1, "y" -> 1}`.

I want to get the value of sub property `x`(I tried `data.x` -- since I'm a Java programmer -- didn't work), but I don't know how to do it. I read some document about `json`, but all those doc presents is how to import and export json.

Could any one give me some suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Using the result of functions that return replacement rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5478) and at documentation about `Rule` replacement, etc.

Comment: @Kuba Really thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result of importing a file in JSON format is a list of rules.  For information about ways to use rules, see the documentation for [Applying Transformation Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).

Here is an example:

```
data = ImportString["{\"x\":1, \"y\":{\"a\":2, \"b\":[3, 4]}}", "JSON"]
(* {"x" -> 1, "y" -> {"a" -> 2, "b" -> {3, 4}}} *)
```

Retrieving a top-level property is straight-forward:

```
"x" /. data
(* 1 *)
```

Retrieving nested properties is a bit more awkward:

```
"b" /. ("y" /. data)
(* {3, 4} *)

("b" /. ("y" /. data))[[2]]
(* 4 *)
```

Starting with *Mathematica* version 10.2, the new RawJSON format is a little more convenient to work with:

```
data = ImportString["{\"x\":1, \"y\":{\"a\":2, \"b\":[3, 4]}}", "RawJSON"]
(* <| "x" -> 1, "y" -> <| "a" -> 2, "b" -> {3, 4} |>|> *)
```

It returns [associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) for objects instead of rule lists.  Associations offer a nicer syntax for accessing elements:

```
data[["x"]]
(* 1 *)

data[["y", "b"]]
(* {3, 4} *)

data[["y", "b", 2]]
(* 4 *)
```

When processing really complicated JSON trees, the [Dataset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and [Query](http://Query) functionality might prove to be useful.